# Create a simple flow relating to any table in Sql Server in Wexflow in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, wexflow

Create a simple flow relating to any table in SQL Server in Wexflow in Dotnet core 
I installed the Dotnet Core runtime.

I saw the example https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow but in this only XML are there. How to use in Dotnet core?

Please help me !!!

Comment: Have you tried the examples from https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow ?

Comment: In this only XML are there but how to use in Dotnet core? @mjwills

Comment: Can .NET Core generate XML?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow/wiki/Custom-tasks ?